# Fully Dynamic DataTable PHP

Tags: php, json, datatable

I'm trying to create a fully dynamic datatable opening in a modal. At first it gives me the correct results, but when i open a new modal it gives me this error:

> DataTables warning: table id=tableDetails - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/3

Hope you can help. Thank you.

Here's the code i'm using:
[Modal]:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="modalTitle"></h4>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered" id="tableDetails"></table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[DataTable]

```
$.getJSON( "controller/kpi.php", {
    abrArq: abreviatesArq,
    idKpi: idKpi
}, function(detailsKpi){        

    var detailsHeader = "";
    var detailsBody = "";

    //Validar 'thead' 
    if(detailsKpi["tableH"])
    {
        $("#tableDetails").append('<thead id="detailsHeader"></thead>');
    }


    $("#tableDetails").append('<tbody id="detailsBody"></tbody>');


    //Validar 'tbody'
    if(detailsKpi["tableB"])
    {   
        $("#tableDetails").append('<tbody id="detailsBody"></tbody>');

        //Header Tabela
        detailsHeader += "<tr>";
            $.each(detailsKpi["tableH"], function(dkHind, dkHobj){
                var string = dkHobj.toUpperCase();

                detailsHeader += "<th>";
                    detailsHeader += string;
                detailsHeader += "</th>";
            });
        detailsHeader += "</tr>";


        //Body Tabela
        $.each(detailsKpi["tableB"], function(dkBind, dkBobj)
        {
            detailsBody += '<tr>';
                $.each(detailsKpi["tableH"], function(dkHindex, dkHobjecto)
                {
                    detailsBody += '<td>';
                        detailsBody += dkBobj[dkHobjecto];
                    detailsBody += '</td>';
                });
            detailsBody += '</tr>';
        });
    }
    //Se não existerem resultados apresenta mensagem
    //'Não foram encontrados resultados'
    else
    {
        detailsBody = "<div class='noResults'>Não foram encontrados resultados</div>";
        $("#tableDetails").removeClass("table-bordered");
    }


    //Anexar Informação na tabela
    $("#detailsHeader").append(detailsHeader);
    $("#detailsBody").append(detailsBody);


    //Chamar DataTable
    $('#tableDetails').DataTable({
        //Número de registos a mostrar por página
        "aLengthMenu": [
            [10, 50, -1],
            [10, 50, "Tudo"]
        ],
        //Textos usados nas datatables
        "oLanguage": {
            "sSearch": "Pesquisar:",
            "sLengthMenu": "Mostra _MENU_ por página",
            "sInfoEmpty": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
            "sInfo": "Total de _TOTAL_ registos para mostrar (_START_ a _END_)",
            "sEmptyTable": "Sem dados disponíveis na tabela",
            "sInfoFiltered": " - filtrado de _MAX_ registos",
            "sZeroRecords": "Não foram encontrados nenhuns registos",
            "oPaginate": {
                "sFirst": "Primeira Página",
                "sLast": "Última Página",
                "sNext": "Seguinte",
                "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            }
        },
    });
});


//Limpar Modal #1
$("#detailsHeader").text("");
$("#detailsBody").text("");
```

[Query]

```
$this->cleanErrors();
        $this->sql->cleanErrors();

        $table = $param["abrArq"].'_kpi'.$param["idKpi"].'_detail';


        //SELECT COLUMNS
        $columns = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table;
        $this->sql->query($columns);

        $detCol = array();
        while($cRow = $this->sql->fetchRow())
        {
            $detCol[] = $table.'.'.$cRow["Field"];
        };
        $listCol = implode(", ", $detCol);


        //SELECT RESULTS
        $query="SELECT ".
                    $listCol."
                FROM ".
                    $table;
        $this->sql->query($query);


        //echo $query;


        if($this->sql->hasErrors())
        {
            $this->errors = $this->errors + $this->sql->errors;
            return false;
        }

        while($row = $this->sql->fetchRow())
        {
            $res[] = $row;
        }

        if($this->sql->hasErrors())
        {
            $this->errors = $this->errors + $this->sql->errors;
            return false;
        }

        return $res;
```

Comment: the js code is the [DataTable] code i added in the post

Comment: is it possible that you reinitialise the table later in your code?

Comment: Can you help me do that? I added the "destroy" option "bDestroy": true. Now it reads, but after i open the modal the second it loses the DataTable pagination, search, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Include only once datatable js in main page.
Delete every js code that initialise  datatable in main page.
Add js code to initialise in modal after footer in script tag.

if this don't work try to add data table destroy on js when the modal begin dismiss.

I hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common problem that you can avoid (...) Reading Datatable Documentation deeply. I pass many  hours one time with your same issue.

Finally y solved it destroing any datatable initializacion before create my table, in your case you want to add an :

```
 if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#myAwesomeTable') ) {
  $('#myAwesomeTable').DataTable().destroy();
}
```

Rigth before initialization

```
 if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#myAwesomeTable') ) {
      $('#myAwesomeTable').DataTable().destroy();
    }




        $('#myAwesomeTable').DataTable({
            "responsive": true,
            "processing" : true,
            "ajax" : {
                "url" : "...",
                dataSrc : ''
            },
            "columns" : [
            {
                "data" : "id"
            }, {
                "data" : "name"
            }]
        }).draw(true).columns.adjust();
      },
      error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
              console.log("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
      }
    });
});
```

In the Url you can use a php file that willhave a simpl PDO PHP MYSQL call and you can echo whit a json_encode function like this :

```
<?php

require "../../../class/PDO.class.php";
require "../../../class/helper.class.php";

$new = $_POST['id'];
$mundialorder = $_POST['irOrder'];

//var_dump($_POST);

 $valores = array(
      $new,
      $mundialorder
      );

 $DB = new Db(DBHost, DBName, DBUser, DBPassword);

    $sql = "UPDATE me SET please= ? WHERE person = ?";


    if($DB->query($sql,$valores) > 0)  {

            //$usuario = Helper::obtain_my_simple_JSON();

             $msg = "S";





        $data['success'] = true;
        $data['message'] = "good";

    }else{
        $data['success'] = false;
        $data['errors'] = "Error";
    }



echo json_encode($data);
```

?>